# Hiding Number Pad in iPhone

Tags: iphone

How can I hide the Number Pad programmatically in iPhone?

As I have created a Registration Form and for the ZIP/Postal Code I have set keypad as NumberPad.

So on entering numbers I would like to hide the NumberPad?

Comment: You want to hide the pad when someone enters numbers? How should someone enter numbers when the numpad always hides on entering?

Answer (score 2):

//put in viewdidload.

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    [super.... ];
}
 - (void) hideKeyboard 
{
    [textfieldname1 resignFirstResponder];
    [textfieldname2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Send resignFirstResponder to the UI element to which the keyboard is linked (probably a UITextField/UITextView?).